# Unable to add a Server to Eclipse Photon

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

I've recently installed Eclipse Photon.  I have an earlier version (Mars) that still works fine.

In installing it I just downloaded the zip file oepe-12.2.1.9-photon-distro-win32-x86_64.zip from https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/oepe-v12219-downloads.html - and then launched it after the download.

It starts up okay - but obviously something isn't quite right.

For one thing I can't add a WL server.  The Define a New Server dialog looks like this - which won't allow me to actually add any of my WL server installations...

[image]

When it should look like this (from my old Mars installation)...

[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks much

Comment: Did you click the "Add..." link to add your weblogic installation ?

Comment: I did.  In fact I pretty much tried everything - nothing worked.  Now all of a sudden it's working, looks normal, and I can actually add a server.  I have absolutely no idea what I did differently.

Comment: Thanks for the advice though :)

Comment: What is the error raised by OEPE ?